# What type of fertilizer should be used on garlic?

Tags: fertilizer, garlic

This is my third year growing garlic and in the past I've sprayed my plants with a liquid [fish](http://www.neptunesharvest.com/fs-191.html) and [seaweed](http://www.neptunesharvest.com/sw-191.html) fertilizer throughout the season. I had also applied a small amount of composted manure in the fall when planting it.

This year when I planted the garlic I did not amend the soil since I didn't have anything to use. Now that it’s coming up I’m wondering when this should be fertilized, and with what.

I have some bone meal and my local nursery has a bulb care product and some [bio-tone starter plus](http://www.espoma.com/p_consumer/biotone_overview.html) available. Would any of these be ok to apply or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bone meal, like most phosphorous sources, is not mobile in the soil.  A plant has to grow towards it to use it.  I assume you are not going to dig up your garlic in order to add bone meal or bulb care at the roots.

I actually never fertilize my garlic but what it could use in the spring is nitrogen for leaf growth. Nitrogen can be applied as a side dressing or a foliar feed.   The least amount of work would be to apply 1/2" of compost to the plant.

Comment: I also do not fertilize my garlic and it grows just fine.  I do amend my soil with compost and new dirt every spring though.